# Tumblr Photo Captions in Slide Show mode cut off

Tags: html, css, image, tumblr, caption

I have a problem with the theme on Tumblr called Brick. Whenever I post a photoset, on the entry page when I click on the photoset, a lightbox pops up and I can click through the images. However, my captions (the longer the description and the bigger the photo) are cut off by the edge of the browser.

You can see it in the pic I've uploaded here: http://i60.tinypic.com/xddwcx.png.

I've been poking around the code both the html and css, but I'm not sure what would be the best way to go about this. Is there a simple fix to correct the hidden overflow within tumblr coding? Much appreciated help on the matter in advance! The site is http://movementdetroitblog.tumblr.com and below is my code for the photosets.

```
{block:Photo}
    <div class="photo">

    {block:indexpage}
        <div class="photo-hover">

            <div class="captions">
                <a href="{permalink}">
                    <span>x</span> {Timeago}
                </a>
                <a href="{permalink}">
                    <span>f</span> {NoteCountWithLabel}
                </a>
            </div>

            <a href="{permalink}">
                <div class="overlay"></div>
            </a>

            <div class="larger-width"> 
                <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}"alt="{PhotoAlt}">
            </div>

            <div class="normal-width">
                <img src="{PhotoURL-500}"alt="{PhotoAlt}">
            </div>

        </div>
    {/block:indexpage}

    {block:permalinkpage}
        {LinkOpenTag}
            <img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}"alt="{PhotoAlt}">
        {LinkCloseTag}
    {/block:permalinkpage}

    </div>
{/block:Photo}

{block:Photoset}
     <div class="photo">

        {block:indexpage}
            <div class="photo-hover">
                <div class="captions">
                    <a href="{permalink}">
                        <span>x</span> {Timeago}
                    </a>
                    <a href="{permalink}">
                        <span>f</span> {NoteCountWithLabel}
                    </a>
                    <a href="{permalink}">
                        <span>j</span> view photoset
                    </a>
                </div>
                <a href="{permalink}">
                    <div class="overlay"></div>
                </a>
                <div class="photoset">
                    {block:Photos}
                        <img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}">
                    {/block:Photos}
                </div>
            </div>
        {/block:indexpage}

        {block:permalinkpage}
            <div class="center-element">
                <div class="responsive-level-1">
                    {Photoset-500}
                </div>
                <div class="responsive-level-2">
                    {Photoset-500}
                </div>
                <div class="responsive-level-3">
                    {Photoset-250}
                </div>
            </div>
        {/block:permalinkpage}

    </div>
{/block:Photoset}
```